# Regular usage output with Click command aliases

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface

I'm using this snippet for my custom group (from [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#command-aliases)) to allow prefixes.

```
class AliasedGroup(click.Group):
    def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        rv = click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name)
        if rv is not None:
            return rv
        matches = [x for x in self.list_commands(ctx)
                   if x.startswith(cmd_name)]
        if not matches:
            return None
        elif len(matches) == 1:
            return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, matches[0])
        ctx.fail('Too many matches: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(matches)))
```

The usage output becomes really dumb however: it shows the prefixes of the commands instead of showing them fully:

> Usage: test_core a c [OPTIONS]

I would like to see

> Usage: test_core add combined [OPTIONS]

even when I call `test_core a c -h`.

I've looked into it and it doesn't look like there is an obvious solution. Formatter logic doesn't know about their original names. Maybe `MultiCommand.resolve_command` could be overridden to handle an overridden version of `MultiCommand/Group.get_command` that returns the original command name as well. But that might break some things, maybe there's some easier way.

Full code:

```
import click

class AliasedGroup(click.Group):
    def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        rv = click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name)
        if rv is not None:
            return rv
        matches = [x for x in self.list_commands(ctx)
                    if x.startswith(cmd_name)]
        if not matches:
            return None
        elif len(matches) == 1:
            return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, matches[0])
        ctx.fail('Too many matches: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(matches)))

@click.group(cls=AliasedGroup, context_settings={'help_option_names': ['-h', '--help']})
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group(cls=AliasedGroup)
def add():
    pass

@add.command()
@click.option('--yarr')
def combined():
    pass

cli(['a', 'c', '-h'], prog_name='test_core')
```

Comment: what is your full example program that has this behavior

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah, I should have done that, now it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the aliases used.

The aliases are kept in a global variable because `click` uses a lot of context instances.

And you need to implement your own HelpFormatter. This covers all uses of the help construction.

In the `write_usage` replace the aliases with the full command names. Keep track of aliases filled to cover the case of `test_core a a -h` as a command for `test_core add auto -h`. If an alias is not found in `prog` don't try the next alias used (`while` instead of `for`).

```python
import click

clickAliases = []

class AliasedGroup(click.Group):
    def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
        rv = click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name)
        if rv is not None:
            return rv
        matches = [x for x in self.list_commands(ctx)
                    if x.startswith(cmd_name)]
        if not matches:
            return None
        elif len(matches) == 1:
            clickAliases.append((cmd_name, matches[0]))
            return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, matches[0])
        ctx.fail('Too many matches: %s' % ', '.join(sorted(matches)))

class MyHelpFormatter(click.HelpFormatter):
    def write_usage(self, prog, args="", prefix="Usage: "):
        if clickAliases:
            parts = prog.split()
            partIdx = 0
            for alias,cmd in clickAliases:
                while partIdx < len(parts):
                    if parts[partIdx] == alias:
                        parts[partIdx] = cmd
                        partIdx += 1
                        break
                    partIdx += 1
            prog = ' '.join(parts)
        click.HelpFormatter.write_usage(self, prog, args, prefix)

def make_formatter(self):
    return MyHelpFormatter(width=self.terminal_width, max_width=self.max_content_width)
click.Context.make_formatter = make_formatter
# version 8.x makes if easier with
# click.Context.formatter_class = MyHelpFormatter

@click.group(cls=AliasedGroup, context_settings={'help_option_names': ['-h', '--help']})
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group(cls=AliasedGroup)
def add():
    click.echo("add command")

@add.command()
@click.option('--yarr')
def combined(yarr):
    click.echo(f"combined command: {yarr}")

# simulate command arguments - for debugging
# cli(['a', 'c', '-h'], prog_name='test_core')

# normal start
cli(prog_name='test_core')
```

Terminal output

```
$ python test_core.py a c -h
add command
Usage: test_core add combined [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --yarr TEXT
  -h, --help   Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: `Usage: test_core add combined [OPTIONS]` != `Usage: test_core.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2 [ARGS]...]...`
-- Additionally, command chaining is not my interest. Group hierarchy with command leaves is.

Comment: Output to an invocation with `cli(['a', 'c', '-h'], prog_name='test_core')` is this actually: `Usage: test_core c [OPTIONS]` -- equally bad.

Comment: @MatrixTheatrics You have to write your own `HelpFormatter`. See edit

Comment: Nice job, thanks! I modified it a bit for myself so that the aliases list is stored in the current context's dict obj. I already have these classes/functions overloaded, so it's easily inserted into my code.

Comment: @MatrixTheatrics In my test I found a new context for every argument, or at least a new value for `ctx.command_path`, maybe it was for the same context

Comment: Yes, each command gets a new context, but the obj member is shared among them to my knowledge. I did it like so: `get_command`: `obj = click.get_current_context().ensure_object(dict)` \n `obj.setdefault('_aliases', []).append((cmd_name, matches[0]))`. And `write_usage`: `obj = click.get_current_context().ensure_object(dict)` \n `if obj and '_aliases' in obj and obj['_aliases']:` ...